# Program to find duplicates in array and place them after the unique one in python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I have tried many times to solve this problem but not getting proper answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, and show us what you want, what you're currently getting, or your current error message, and what you've tried so far, also see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also see [**How to write a perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple 4-step solution:

```
arr = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 6, 9, 0]

# isolate unique elements by casting the list to a set
uniques_set = list(set(arr))

# create a list of just duplicates, by removing all unique elements once
duplicates = arr[:]
for u in uniques:
    duplicates.remove(u)

# remove all the duplicate elements from the end of the original list, to get all unique elements in order
# do this by reversing the list, removing from the front, and then re-reversing it
reordered = arr[::-1]
for d in duplicates:
    reordered.remove(d)
reordered = reordered[::-1]

# reinsert duplicate elements immediately after reordered elements
for d in duplicates:
    reordered.insert(reordered.index(d) + 1, d)
```

Running that code produces the following:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 9, 0]
```

Comment: no if i want to take a two empty lists and third list is my input. Then i want that first list stored only unique and second list stored all duplicates. Example: 
list3 = [2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,4,5]
list2 = [2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3]
list1 = [4,5]
i need this type of solution??